# Save file option to save html file at given location in system

Tags: javascript, html

I need to save the same html file at different location.
suppose there is a link or button in HTML file and on click of that it should open save as dialog, then user need to select location and it will save html file at that location.

Can we do this by using html or javascript??
I check and found some solution but that is working only in I.E browser (old versions)?

Comment: That is no possible to do with javascript. You aren't allow to access the hard disk of the users. Otherwise it will be a security problem

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, then is there any way to save it by using html only??

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language, so you can't. This task is not possible to do in a website right now.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="path/to/file/to/download" download>Download</a>
```

It'll force your browser to open the save dialog.

Comment: I already tried that it will open file in browser tab. or page not found error.